# "... Where field ON (SELECT ..)" does not work with "select" in a working where clause

Tags: mysql, select, pdo, inner-join

I need to run a query that looks at the contents on 3 linked tables:

Table a = container of the data we have to extract

Table b = parent table, which contains the ids with which tables a and c are related

Table c = table containing data on the condition to be satisfied

Then: b-> b.id-> on a.bid and b.bid

I tried to make the selection like this:

```
SELECT field_a
FROM a
WHERE field_b IN (SELECT b.id FROM b INNER JOIN c ON b.id = 1 WHERE c.aid = 1)
```

The query:

```
(SELECT b.id FROM b INNER JOIN c ON b.id = 1 WHERE c.aid = 1)
```

returns this result:

```
Array ([0] => Array ([id] => 1))
```

Because I can not execute

```
"SELECT field_a FROM a WHERE field_b IN (SELECT ...)"
```

If I try to do

```
"SELECT field_a FROM a WHERE field_b IN (1)"
```

the query works, but I need to extract it first with select

Comment: Please show sample table data here, and also the output you expect.

Comment: What goes wrong? Error message? Empty result set? Incorrect result set? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @O.Jones Only empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be equivalent to your query:

```
SELECT field_a
FROM a
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM b
             JOIN c ON b.id = 1
             WHERE a.field_b = b.id
               AND c.aid = 1)
```

**BUT** this query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM b
JOIN c ON b.id = 1
WHERE a.field_b = b.id
 AND c.aid = 1
```

or

```
SELECT b.id FROM b INNER JOIN c ON b.id = 1 WHERE c.aid = 1
```

as you have written, is wrong. While it runs and gives correct result, the `ON` clause is not correct - it has nothing to do with `JOIN`. You might want to use another `EXISTS` here, but I am very unsure what are you trying to achieve there...

Comment: It works, but I have a question: how do you know which field to relate to? Are you checking the relationships I created in the database automatically? I'm asking you why we did not specify which field it should belong to and it seems strange to me that the query was successful using simply EXISTS (...)

Comment: @Question I didn't even read carefully you relations, I just saw how you were trying to check your condition - this is common issue. Whenever you are using `IN` or `NOT IN` I recommend using `EXISTS` instead. Read about it and you'll know as much as I do :)